# How do I interpret the very different results given by a logistic regression on a subset of variables?

Tags: r, logistic, multiple-regression

I am trying to understand why the "p" (statistical significance) is so different for two regression models on the same population, one with all variables, the other only with some of the variables.

I would expect the results to be similar in terms of statistical significance.
Why am I wrong?

## Detail:

Having just completed my first course on statistics ([in French](https://www.fun-mooc.fr/courses/course-v1:UPSUD+42001+session07)), my understanding is very imperfect, particularly with respect to multivariate logistics regression.

Following this 5-week-long introductory course to statistics, I decided to test my knowledge on the following dataset to try and understand the relationship between all the explanatory variables and the outcome variable (y in this case).

The dataset is [bank-additional.zip](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00222/), with the [variables described here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Bank+Marketing).

In my attempt to understand the relationship between variables, using `R`, I first re-categorised the data:

```
# Remove all previous objects
rm(list=ls())

# Import libraries
library(gplots)
library(prettyR)
library(corrplot)

# Read the data
b<-read.csv2("bank-additional.csv")

# Check the data
#str(b)
#print(table(b$nr.employed))

# Refactor categorical and numeric data
b$emp.var.rate   <- as.numeric(as.character(b$emp.var.rate))
b$cons.price.idx <- as.numeric(as.character(b$cons.price.idx))
b$cons.conf.idx  <- as.numeric(as.character(b$cons.conf.idx))
b$euribor3m      <- as.numeric(as.character(b$euribor3m))
b$nr.employed    <- as.numeric(as.character(b$nr.employed))
b$emp.var.rate   <- as.numeric(as.character(b$emp.var.rate))

# Recode missing values
b$pdays[b$pdays==999] <- NA

# Re-check the data
str(b)
#print(table(b$nr.employed))
print(describe(b))
```

Then, I attempted a first model with all variables:

```
# Compute the binomial multivariate regression model
m <- glm(y ~ age+job+marital+education+default+housing+loan+contact+month+day_of_week+duration+campaign+pdays+previous+poutcome+emp.var.rate+cons.price.idx+cons.conf.idx+euribor3m+nr.employed, b, family=binomial)
print(drop1(m,.~.,test="Chisq"))
```

I, maybe incorrectly, understood that the following variables were not statistically significant:

```
Model:
y ~ age + job + marital + education + default + housing + loan + 
    contact + month + day_of_week + duration + campaign + pdays + 
    previous + poutcome + emp.var.rate + cons.price.idx + cons.conf.idx + 
    euribor3m + nr.employed

               Df Deviance    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
age             1   58.052 154.05  0.227 0.6334552    
marital         2   58.500 152.50  0.675 0.7134888    
default         1   60.295 156.29  2.471 0.1159764    
contact         1   60.146 156.15  2.321 0.1276123    
day_of_week     4   64.703 154.70  6.879 0.1424439    
campaign        1   58.366 154.37  0.542 0.4615772    
pdays           1   59.303 155.30  1.479 0.2239809    
previous        1   57.926 153.93  0.101 0.7503597    
poutcome        1   59.938 155.94  2.113 0.1460316
```

While those were:

```
job            11   87.480 163.48 29.656 0.0017941 ** 
education       6   84.294 170.29 26.470 0.0001819 ***
housing         1   62.500 158.50  4.676 0.0305929 *  
loan            1   63.091 159.09  5.267 0.0217320 *  
month           9  108.087 188.09 50.262 9.615e-08 ***
duration        1  108.622 204.62 50.798 1.024e-12 ***
emp.var.rate    1   66.978 162.98  9.153 0.0024828 ** 
cons.price.idx  1   70.983 166.98 13.159 0.0002862 ***
cons.conf.idx   1   84.029 180.03 26.204 3.071e-07 ***
euribor3m       1   68.756 164.76 10.931 0.0009455 ***
nr.employed     1   69.215 165.22 11.391 0.0007380 ***
```

However, if I try to compute a regression model with only the statistically significant variables, I get a very different result, and I do not understand why this is.

```
m <- glm(y ~ job+education+housing+loan+month+duration+emp.var.rate+cons.price.idx+cons.conf.idx+euribor3m+nr.employed, b, family=binomial)
print(drop1(m,.~.,test="Chisq"))
```

The second model gives me this:

```
Model:
y ~ job + education + housing + loan + month + duration + emp.var.rate + 
    cons.price.idx + cons.conf.idx + euribor3m + nr.employed

               Df Deviance    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
<none>              1673.9 1747.9                     
job            11   1688.5 1740.5  14.67   0.19809    
education       7   1676.6 1736.6   2.74   0.90779    
housing         1   1674.0 1746.0   0.10   0.74975    
loan            1   1674.2 1746.2   0.29   0.58919    
month           9   1755.5 1811.5  81.67  7.52e-14 ***
duration        1   2299.6 2371.6 625.73 < 2.2e-16 ***
emp.var.rate    1   1674.8 1746.8   0.93   0.33576    
cons.price.idx  1   1674.4 1746.4   0.48   0.48983    
cons.conf.idx   1   1676.6 1748.6   2.75   0.09706 .  
euribor3m       1   1674.0 1746.0   0.07   0.79474    
nr.employed     1   1674.9 1746.9   1.05   0.30568
```

I would welcome any layman enough explanation, particularly one that that can help me understand when I can or cannot use a model calculated in this manner and why the p values are so different for the subset of variables vs. the full list of variables.

Comment: Looking just at statistical significance is unlikely to help you here. What happens if you look at the coefficients instead? Do they change in a substantive way between your two very different models?

Comment: I thought that statistical significance (p) was the first step before considering anything else. What point is there comparing coefficients if they are not significant?

Comment: Suppose my small study shows men are 5cm taller than women but it is not statistically significant. Your study shows men are 5cm taller than women but because it is much larger it is statistically significant. I think they showed the same thing as far as the heights of men and women are concerned.

Comment: Ok but I don't see how this relates to my question: I use the same population, one with all variables, the other only with some of the variables. I would expect the results to ve similar in terms of statistical significance. Vut why am I wrong - since it seems to clearly not be the case?